# Find how many sets of numbers within a range exist

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search, range

I have a column of 1 million numbers that were generated randomly. They range from 1 - 1000, and each have two decimal points. There are duplicates of numbers obviously.

I would like to create a function which tells me how many sequences of numbers fall within a certain range. For example:

How many sequences of 10 numbers between 56-60 are there?
Or, how many sequences of 20 numbers between 56-60 are there?
Or, how many sequences of 50 numbers between 1-10 are there?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How are you defining a "sequence"?

Comment: By "sequence of numbers" I mean 2 or more numbers that are adjacent to each other in the list. Take for example these ten randomly numbers:  

1.00, 1.11, 3.45, 54.23, 1.67, 2.88, 3.00, 34.54, 23.52, 67.78

I would like to be able to know "how many sequences of THREE numbers between 1.00 - 4.00 are there? And the answer would be 2 sequences (1.00, 1.11, 3.45... and 1.67, 2.88, 3.00). 

Make sense? Sorry it's so convoluted. I'm not sure the best way to ask and I've searched far and wide for the answer but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1617664/edit) and provide sample data and expected output. What you've tried so far would also be useful, so we don't go down already covered ground for nothing

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a sample about your requirement, please confirm if this will help you.

```
=(SUMPRODUCT((A1:C10>H1)*(A1:C10<I1)))/H2
```

[image]
[image]